# Read header from fetch response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-security, oauth

I have a Spring boot server that uses an authentication filter to return a JWT header called "Autorization".
My JS-react application consumes this login call (CORS) using the "fetch" method that gets a response.
I already know that there are standard response headers, and that Authorization is not one of them, so I made the server return Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization , along with the
Authorization header itself:

somehow I can see the header returning on the browser dev tools, but not in JS:

```
return fetch(url, {
            headers,
            ...options
        })
            .then(this._checkStatus)
            .then(response => {
                //response.json()
                const headers = response.headers.entries();
                       let header = headers.next();
                       while (!header.done){
                         console.log(header.value);
                         header = header.next();
                       }
                return {id_token : response.headers.get('Authorization')};
            })
```

'Authorization' does not get printed.

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi....ewlsTNGyg
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 06:33:46 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Console prints:

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
AuthService.js:82 content-length: 0
AuthService.js:82 expires: 0
AuthService.js:82 pragma: no-cache
```

Tried Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization with or without the capital "A".

Comment: Have you tried checking in the first then block?

Comment: use `response.getHeader('Authorization')`

Comment: try debug with `for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) { console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]); }`

Comment: Thanks. still can't get my header.